# python : colspan in texttable

Tags: python, freetexttable

```
table = Texttable()
table.set_deco(Texttable.HEADER | Texttable.VLINES | Texttable.HLINES | Texttable.BORDER)
table.add_rows([ ["Name", "Age", "Nickname"],
                     ["Xavier Huon", 32, "Xav'"],
                     ["Baptiste Clement", 1, "Baby"] ])
print table.draw()
```

result:

[image]

how i can make this?

[image]

Comment: Your result is empty, please share info about the result you expect

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: i will change table 1 to table 2, how to change the table?

Answer (score 2):

There's no real good way to do it with `texttable`. For instance, it doesn't seem to understand there can be additional grouped lists underneath a main header.

Instead, you can accomplish this with some clever formatting:

```
>>> table = Texttable()
>>> table.set_deco(Texttable.HEADER | Texttable.VLINES | Texttable.HLINES | Texttable.BORDER)
>>> 
>>> table.add_rows([ ["Name\nfirst   |   last", "Age", "Nickname"],
...                      ["Xavier   |    Huon", 32, "Xav'"],
...                      ["Baptiste | Clement", 1, "Baby"] ])
>>> print table.draw()
+--------------------+-----+----------+
|        Name        | Age | Nickname |
|  first   |   last  |     |          |
+====================+=====+==========+
| Xavier   |    Huon | 32  | Xav'     |
+--------------------+-----+----------+
| Baptiste | Clement | 1   | Baby     |
+--------------------+-----+----------+
```

The only issue would be aligning the `first` and `last` name items should the table grow larger with a longer name. You could however do some math to determine the largest name, then use string formatting to left and right align it. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader (and [apparently double poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112770/python-customize-texttable)).

Comment: not use \n
but cols 'name' colspan2
how colspan in the texttable?

Comment: @RobbyZhi: You can't.